# Trimming a Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, trim

I am supposed to write a method that takes in two integers as a min and max. Then it removes any integers from the tree that are less than the minimum and larger than the maximum. The code I have so far is very ugly and does not work at all. I'm not even sure if it I am on the correct path or not...

```
private SearchTree<Integer> trim(SearchTreeNode<Integer> e, int min, int max){
    if (e != null){
        if (e.left.data.compareTo(min) <= 0){
            remove((E) e.left);
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Imagine how you would do it by hand, and then try to code the method in Java.

Comment: If you were given a sorted list, and had to remove all elements less than a specific minimum, how would you do it? How is a binary search tree like a sorted list? How is it different?

Comment: +1 @ChrisJ. It sucks to do, and it only gets worse as your problems get harder, but there's nothing better for actually understanding it and getting it done.

Comment: Why don't you recurse down the tree before you start deleting elements. It might help you a little bit ;)

Answer (score 2):

Some general ideas about the algorithm without any code:

You need to implement `delete` first. `delete` in a Binary Search Tree has specific and well-defined behavior; you need to implement this first (your professor should have gone over it). I'd say that 80% of your work is done here.

The remaining 20% is for implementing the `find` function. You can now combine both functions and implement your `trim` function.

If you explain what you have done so far, we might be able to give you some hints and move you in the correct direction. The important thing here is to learn!

**UPDATE**

Yes, you need to traverse the tree and delete nodes that meet the criteria. As far as recursion is concerned, think about how you would traverse the binary search tree normally.

Now you need to add in the `contains` and the `remove`. That part is trivial, but the tricky part is that the tree is changing as you are traversing it. But if you think about it, it shouldn't be that hard. Hint: When you delete a node in a BST, you don't actually *remove* it unless it's a leaf node. You merely replace its value. So traversal shouldn't be affected.

Comment: I have "remove" and "contains" methods. Could I use the contains method to check if the tree contains values that are more or less than the max and min? And I'm guessing if that returns true, then I would run the remove method. However, I'm unsure how to implement the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo code for your problem is.

```
node trim(node e, int min ,int max){
  if(min < e.data && max < e.data){
     return trim(e.left,min,max);
  }else if(min > e.data && max > e.data){
     return trim(e.right,min,max);
  }else {
     if(min <= e.data && e.left != null && min > e.left.data){
       e.left=null;
     } else {
      trim(e.left, min,max);
     }

     if(max >= e.data && e.right !=null && e.right.data > max){
       e.right=null;
     }else{
       trim(e.right, min,max);
     }
     return e;
   }
}
```

Comment: -1: I don't think this code is correct. You're completely eliminating a subtree. That's now how deletions work in a BST.

Comment: This is not a balanced BST. So this should work and deleted part will be garbage collected.I'm eliminating complete subtree becase its less then min or more then max. I thought thats the question was all about.

Comment: Typically when you talk about deleting a node from a BST, you don't delete the entire subtree.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could implement the iterator interface, go through the elements that constitute your BST, whichever element meets your constraint is put in a new BST
then you make your original BST equal to the new one.

Regards.